# How do i copy from a dateonly column to a datetime column in Dynamics 365 CE?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, power-platform

I have the column Birthday (BirthDate), on table Contact, having Format - DateOnly. I want to create a calculated column BirthDateTime, on table Contact, having Format - DateTime and populate it from BirthDate. How can I do that? Or the way around?

The reason I am asking is that I want to use DIFFINYEARS for calculating age and it is not possible to compare BirthDate with NOW(), ie. DIFFINYEARS(BirthDate,NOW()) due to difference in Format. Otherwise it seemed to be a simple solution.

Comment: Why not simply truncate `NOW()` instead of introducing a new attribute just for that purpose?

Comment: Truncate NOW()?! NOW is a Dynamics 365 CE builtin function returning a User Local DateTime-value. I can´t see how that would solve my iniitial problem.

Comment: I found this in my search for a solution and it appears a business rule might solve my problem, https://www.ais.com/how-to-create-an-exact-age-field-in-microsoft-powerapps-and-dynamics/

Comment: `NOW()` isn't a Dynamics 365 CE builtin function; it is provided by Power Platform. Did you already check [Power Fx DateValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-datevalue-timevalue#datevalue)?

Comment: I still don't see how truncating NOW() would solve my case

Comment: It will allow you to compare your existing `DateOnly` to the truncated `NOW()` without the need to introduce and maintain a new field.